# Scrape player stats from NHL-API

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, web-scraping

Trying to scrape each individual players stats from a game, but ran into trouble when trying the .get() method.

This is the API:
https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020002/feed/live

To scrape the player stats I first need their ID. The first for loop does that by getting to ('skaters') and grabbing their ID and putting it 
in the list player_id.

The next two for loops is to get player stats both for home/away and for every ID in player_id. Player ID is in the form of of number => 8474756
But to the Key to grab the player_stats is named "ID"THE PLAYERS NUMBER"", so each key has a unique name, and thats why the for loop is there. But I don't know exactly how to make it work. 
Thank you for your help!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

results = []
player_id = []
 for game_id in range(2018020001, 2018020002, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/feed/live'.format(game_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    game_data = r.json()

for homeaway in ['home','away']:
    player_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('skaters')
    player_id.append(player_dict)

for homeaway in ['home', 'away']:
    for playerID in player_id:
        play_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams')
        .get('homeaway').get('players').get('ID'+player_id).get('person')
```

Here is the code I have to scrape game data, I would like to have the same type of output like this gives me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

results = []
for game_id in range(2018020598, 2018020650, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/boxscore'.format(game_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    game_data = r.json()

    for homeaway in ['home','away']:

    game_dict = game_data.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats')
    game_dict['team'] = game_data.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    game_dict['homeaway'] = homeaway
    game_dict['game_id'] = game_id
    results.append(game_dict)


df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Here is an example table of how I would like the dataset to look like

```
PlayerID   Team   Won/lost   opponent   game_id     metric1   metric2 metric_n
  1          LA      1          CAP       0001         10       10        10
```

Comment: Can you share desired output? How do you want result of script execution look like?

Comment: I can post the code I wrote when I scraped the game data. I would like to have the same type of output. I will also post an example table of how I want It to look like. Posted more info in EDIT section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `player_id` is *list of lists*, so when you do `for playerID in player_id:` you actually iterates through sub-lists, but not player IDs.. Try to modify your code:

```
player_id = {}
results = []

for homeaway in ['home','away']:
    player_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('skaters')
    player_id[homeaway] = player_dict
```

Now `player_id` is a dictionary, like `{'home': [ID_1, ID_2,...],`away`: [ID_3, ID_4, ...]}`

```
for homeaway in player_id:
    for playerID in player_id[homeaway]:
        play_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('person')
        results.append(play_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, precicly the results I wanted! Thank you Mister. Andrersson, worked like a charm!